# Create Endpoint and Binding on client from WCF metadata (IMessageExchange)

Tags: wcf

Is this posible?
If i have a wcf service running + mex,wsHttpBinding or netTcp or any other
I want to create Client Endpoint and Binding in runtime so that when client connects he asks server what kind of Binding is it using and configures it itself for that binding
So that i can change binding without changing lots of configutation on client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it affter google and reading some stuf and trying things out

```
MetadataExchangeClient client = new MetadataExchangeClient(new Uri(mexEndpoint), MetadataExchangeClientMode.MetadataExchange);
        client.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
        MetadataSet m = client.GetMetadata();
        WsdlImporter im = new WsdlImporter(m);
        ServiceEndpointCollection endpoints = im.ImportAllEndpoints();
```

with this i can get all endpoint that are assosieted with that mex endpoint